# Does OSX 10.9.1 have fontconfig installed by default?

Tags: font, font-book

I found at least the manual from my Macbook air.
I have installed XCode full package.

**How can you see if you have fontconfig?**
I cannot find any such command in terminal nor in Fontbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not provided by the system (nor the XCode installation). But you can get it with

- [MacPort](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/graphics/fontconfig/Portfile) (`sudo port install fontconfig`)
- [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/fontconfig.rb) (`brew install fontconfig`)